# AutoresizingMask Not Working in Click Events

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have created a custom button in viewDidLoad() Method and set Autoresizingmask. It works well. But When I Put the same code in Button Click event It Doesn't Autoresized. Is there anyother way to access the `AutoresizingMask` within Click Events? Thanks in Advance.

**Enter code here**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
 UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [button setTitle:@"Show View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    button.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
    button.frame=CGRectMake(20, 373, 73, 43);
        button.autoresizingMask=(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth);
    [self.view addSubview:button];
}


-(IBAction)btn_clicked
{

 UIButton *btn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [btn setTitle:@"Dynamic Btn" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

enter code here
    btn.backgroundColor=[UIColor yellowColor];
    btn.frame=CGRectMake(20, 150, 73, 43);
    btn.autoresizingMask=UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    [self.view addSubview:btn];
}
```

Comment: What do you actually mean by "AutoresizingMask Not Working"? What did you expect on button click??

Comment: Is it AutoresizingMask not working or is it the adding the subview?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- (void)layoutSubviews

The default implementation of this method does nothing on iOS 5.1 and earlier. Otherwise, the default implementation uses any constraints you have set to determine the size and position of any subviews.

Subclasses can override this method as needed to perform more precise layout of their subviews. You should override this method only if the autoresizing and constraint-based behaviors of the subviews do not offer the behavior you want. You can use your implementation to set the frame rectangles of your subviews directly.

You should not call this method directly. If you want to force a layout update, call the setNeedsLayout method instead to do so prior to the next drawing update. If you want to update the layout of your views immediately, call the layoutIfNeeded method.

With reference to Apple document in case of AutoresizingMask not working we need override the above method. AutoresizingMask works when the view frame is changed within - (void)layoutSubviews.

```
enter code here

-(void)layoutSubviews
{
    NSLog(@"layoutSubviews called");
    CGRect viewsize=[[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds];
    view.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, viewsize.size.height);
}
```

Trying the Above code Your AutoresizingMask works well in both iPhone4 and iPhone5.

Answer (score 0):

- (void)viewDidLoad

{

```
[super viewDidLoad];

UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

[button setTitle:@"Show View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

button.frame=CGRectMake(20, 73, 173, 43);

[button addTarget:self action:@selector(btn_clicked:)
```

forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

```
[self.view addSubview:button];
```

}

-(IBAction)btn_clicked:(id)sender

{
    UIButton *btn = (UIButton*)sender;

```
[btn setTitle:@"Dynamic" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[UIView animateWithDuration: 0.4
                 animations: ^{
                     btn.frame=CGRectMake(20, 73, 100, 43);
                     [UIView commitAnimations];
                 }completion: ^(BOOL finished){
                 }];
```

}

Answer (score -1):

i think you need to **typecast** your `UIButton` through its click event. make your `touchUpInside` event like this

```
-(IBAction)btn_clicked:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *btn = (UIButton*)sender;
    [btn setTitle:@"Dynamic Btn" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    //enter code here
    btn.backgroundColor=[UIColor yellowColor];
    btn.frame=CGRectMake(20, 150, 73, 43);
    btn.autoresizingMask=UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    [self.view addSubview:btn];
}
```

And call this click like this `@selector(btn_clicked:)` or connect it via `Interface Builder`
See if this work....

Answer (score -1):

Please use below code may help you:

```
-(IBAction)btn_clicked
{
  UIButton *btn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
  [btn setTitle:@"Dynamic Btn" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  btn.backgroundColor=[UIColor yellowColor];
  btn.frame=CGRectMake(20, 150, 73, 43);
  btn.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
  self.view.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
self.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
btn.autoresizingMask=UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
[self.view addSubview:btn];
}
```

Comment: I have tried this.Eventhough its not working. Pls help me out to solve this issue.